# What are impact when Reorganize MariaDB table partition?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have master and slave replication database.
I have a table with 10m rows. I set partition by rang monthly such as p_201701, p_201702, .. and include 'p_future'. In master, I plan to reorganize my partition 'p_future' into 'p_201711' and 'p_future'. I plan to reorganize with below query.

- What are impact to my database when I run this query?
- Will it prevent my table from insert, update or not?
- What are impact to my replication slave?

..

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_history
    REORGANIZE PARTITION p_future INTO(
    PARTITION p_201711 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2017-12-01')),
    PARTITION p_future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    );
```

Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

(Sounds like you read my http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint )

If you perform the `REORGANIZE` just before needing the `LESS THAN '2017-12-01'` partition, there should be virtually no impact.  This is because `p_future` should be empty, and nothing is yet storing into the new partition.

I say "virtually no impact" because there will be some brief meta locks on the table, etc., but no data to shovel around.

The technique is sort of "failsafe" because if you fail to run the query, everything continues to work.  New rows go (erroneously) into p_future, and `SELECTs` will find them.  Eventually, you need to run the script (and it will be slower) in order to create the new partition and move rows from p_future into it.

You tagged it with [replication], but there should be no impact on on/by replication.  For Galera, TOI should be the right way to do the `ALTER`.